# Help! (initramfs) failed boot

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue, initramfs

I cant boot to my ubuntu 15.04, after boot I get to initramfs. After looking for solutions online and here, I'm not sure what I can do to get back my OS and files...

I introduced the command blkid but I don't know what that is. I'm trying to find a solution and not loose my files, I don't know what to do.

I have an ubuntu USB live, and had tried the boot-repair, but now I cant boot grub2 and instead I'm on grub rescue>

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

(initramfs) blkid <br/>
/dev/sda1: UUID="513ffff2-7be9-4ca7-8ccb-740fa815e0bc" TYPE="ext2"<br/>
/dev/sda5: UUID="732492df-7da7-4b39-a2df-dc7ecbe57134" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"<br/>
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UUI" UUID="2CFF-8706" TYPE="vfat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a live USB and boot your system.

Make sure you can mount your main partition in which your Ubuntu is installed. Lets assume it is `/dev/sda1`

Unmount that partition (NECESSARY).

Now run this command which will fix errors in partition:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sda1
```

Make sure you you can mount the partition.

Restart your system. it should work now.

(I faced with this problem today, I did exactly same thing and problem solved)